# Identify and populate a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

It's a riddle for me: what is the syntax to populate a listbox? But first: how do you identify a listbox? In many forums I read: `ListBox1.Additem`... But how do they know it's 'ListBox1'?

Answer (score 2):

That's the default name for a `ListBox` control when you add it to your form. VB and VBA automatically name new or unnamed controls with the name of the *type* of control, suffixed with an integer identifier.

It's completely irrelevant what your control is called. The point of the sample code is to demonstrate a concept. You should replace `ListBox1` with whatever your control is named.

And you should *definitely* name your controls something other than the default, because as you observe here, it's not very descriptive.

It [used to be recommended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173738) by everyone to name controls following some type of quasi-Hungarian notation with a 3-letter prefix indicating the type of control, followed by your regular descriptive name. Over the past few years, there's been a big backlash against anything that looks like Hungarian notation, but I think it's still quite useful with regards to naming GUI controls, so I still use it. For a `ListBox` control, I might call it something like: `lstCustomers` or `lstItemsForSale`. But it's completely optional: again, what you choose to name your controls is irrelevant to how the code works or how the application will behave.

So, to populate a listbox in VB 6 and/or VBA, you'd use the following code, where `myListBox` is the name of your `ListBox` control:

```
' Add an item to the end of the list
myListBox.AddItem "Peaches"

' Insert an item at the top of the list
myListBox.AddItem "Apples", 0

' Remove the first item in the list
myListBox.RemoveItem 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to populate a listbox now. But what I still don't know is how to give the object a name. With a command button you could edit it in the properties, but with a listbox there are only a few options, like a title and a tag.

Comment: I do not understand this remark.  `ListBox` has more properties than `CommandButton`.  Both have property `(Name)` with the default value of "ListBox1" or "CommandButton1" ready for replacement.

Comment: Yes, but how do I trace this name? How could I look it up (in Word)?

Comment: From within Word: (1) Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor (or Alt+F11). (2) Insert -> UserForm. (3) Add ListBox to Form from ToolBox. (4) Click F4 to view Properties Window.  (5) The top property is (Name).  If you reply please include @TonyDallimore so I am told you have replied.

Answer (score 2):

`ListBox1.AddItem` is for loading a single column ListBox (CodyGrey's answer covers that).

If you are using a multi column ListBox (property `.ColumnCount` > 1), then you need to load an Array into `.List`.  The following snippet loads 3 rows into a 2 column ListBox

```
Dim dat(0 To 2, 0 To 1) As Variant

dat(0, 0) = "A"
dat(0, 1) = "B"
dat(1, 0) = "C"
dat(1, 1) = "D"
dat(2, 0) = "E"
dat(2, 1) = "F"

ListBox1.List = dat
```

---

Accessing the List Box:  (this will vary for different versions of Word, this is for 2003)

To access the ListBox properties:

1. Display the "Control Toolbox" toolbar
2. Go To Design Mode
3. Click the control, and select Properties on the "Control Toolbox"
4. The Name property should now be visible and editable
5. Other properties, such as ColumnCount etc can also be set

Comment: +1.  `AddItem` is very convenient but as Chris points out it is no use for multi-column list boxes.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't helpful for Word :(.

Comment: Excuse my late comment to this old post dating from 2012.  You might consider to modify the narrow view that `ListBox1.AddItem` **is** *for loading a single column ListBox*, whereas *using a multi column ListBox (property `.ColumnCount > 1`)* **needs** *loading an array into `.List`*. - It is possible to apply `.AddItem` in connection with `.List(.ListCount - 1, i) = ...` also for multi column elements and* to assign an array to a one-column `.List`. Without any doubt the Array method has the benefit to overcome the initial 10-columns limit ... @ChrisNeilson

Comment: ...; in connection with `.AddItem` its even possible to specify a `VarIndex` for eventual row insertions regardless of this limit.

Answer (score 1):

When using VBA in Access, a good way to fill in the whole listbox at once is to use the RowSource property when the ListBox is a ValueList. The AddItem method is a bit slow when adding many entries.

For example, to fill in a list of files from a directory, you could use:

```
Dim src As String
Dim S as String

S = Dir(FullPathToCurrentDirectory & "\*.*")

While Len(S) <> 0
        src = src & """" & S & """;"
        S = Dir
Wend
If Len(src) = 0 Then src = """"";"
Me.lstFiles.RowSource = Left(src, Len(src) - 1) ' leave off the last ;
```