# Retrieve items in collection (Excel, VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm getting a Type Mismatch-error, when trying to retrieve items from my collection.

What I mainly want to do, is to collect all customers within as collection, and past all results on my ListBox for visualization. The reason why I'm using a class-module is due to the fact, that UDT are pasting an error: "Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions". So I started programming all properties in classes instead, but I haven't really worked with classes before, so it's pretty new to me.

I'm facing another issue; the .additem-property is limited to 9 columns (on the ListBox), and therefore I'd like to use another method for this. Array is unlimited, and rowsources are limited to 256 or 255. I'd like 14 columns to be shown on the ListBox, and furthermore have the ability to expand if needed later on.

ListView aren't really an option due to the fact, that many computers doesn't have this reference integrated.

Class-module. "clsCustomers"

```
Option Explicit

Private cID As String
Private cCustomerName As String
Private cCompanyName As String
Private cFullName As String
Private cCVR As Long
Private cType As String
Private cGroup As String
Private cCountry As String
Private cStreet As String
Private cZipcode As Variant
Private cCity As String
Private cPhoneNum As Long
Private cMobileNum As Long
Private cEmail As String
Private cInvoiceEmail As String
Private cCreationDate As Date
Private cLastChange As Date
Public Property Get customerID() As String
    customerID = cID
End Property
Public Property Let customerID(value As String)
    cID = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerName() As String
    customerName = cCustomerName
End Property
Public Property Let customerName(value As String)
    cCustomerName = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerCompanyName() As String
    customerCompanyName = cCompanyName
End Property
Public Property Let customerCompanyName(value As String)
    cCompanyName = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerFullName() As String
    customerFullName = cFullName
End Property
Public Property Let customerFullName(value As String)
    cFullName = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerCVR() As Long
    customerCVR = cCVR
End Property
Public Property Let customerCVR(value As Long)
    cCVR = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerType() As String
    customerType = cType
End Property
Public Property Let customerType(value As String)
    cType = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerGroup() As String
    customerGroup = cGroup
End Property
Public Property Let customerGroup(value As String)
    cGroup = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerCountry() As String
    customerCountry = cCountry
End Property
Public Property Let customerCountry(value As String)
    cCountry = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerStreet() As String
    customerStreet = cStreet
End Property
Public Property Let customerStreet(value As String)
    cStreet = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerZipcode() As Variant
    customerZipcode = cZipcode
End Property
Public Property Let customerZipcode(value As Variant)
    cZipcode = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerCity() As String
    customerCity = cCity
End Property
Public Property Let customerCity(value As String)
    cCity = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerPhoneNum() As Long
    customerPhoneNum = cPhoneNum
End Property
Public Property Let customerPhoneNum(value As Long)
    cPhoneNum = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerMobileNum() As Long
    customerMobileNum = cMobileNum
End Property
Public Property Let customerMobileNum(value As Long)
    cMobileNum = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerEmail() As String
    customerEmail = cEmail
End Property
Public Property Let customerEmail(value As String)
    cEmail = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerInvoiceEmail() As String
    customerInvoiceEmail = cInvoiceEmail
End Property
Public Property Let customerInvoiceEmail(value As String)
    cInvoiceEmail = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerCreationDate() As Date
    customerCreationDate = cCreationDate
End Property
Public Property Let customerCreationDate(value As Date)
    cCreationDate = value
End Property
Public Property Get customerLastChange() As Date
    customerLastChange = cLastChange
End Property
Public Property Let customerLastChange(value As Date)
    cLastChange = value
End Property
```

Module. "mExtendedCustomerDatabase". Here I collect my customers within the worksheet("CustomerDatabase").

```
Public CustomerCollection As New Collection
Sub CollectAllCustomers()

    Dim tCustomers As clsCustomers
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerDatabase")

    For i = 1 To wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Set tCustomers = New clsCustomers
        With tCustomers
            .customerID = "Kunde" & wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.CustomerNumber).value
            .customerName = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.InternRef).value
            .customerCompanyName = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.CompanyName).value
            .customerFullName = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.FirstName).value & wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.LastName).value
            .customerCVR = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.CVR).value
            .customerType = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.customerType).value
            .customerGroup = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.customerGroup).value
            .customerCountry = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.Country).value
            .customerStreet = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.Street).value
            .customerZipcode = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.Zipcode).value
            .customerCity = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.City).value
            .customerPhoneNum = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.PhoneNum).value
            .customerMobileNum = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.MobileNum).value
            .customerEmail = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.Email).value
            .customerInvoiceEmail = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.InvoiceEmail).value
            .customerCreationDate = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.CreationDate).value
            .customerLastChange = wks.Cells(i, CustomerDatabase.LastChangeDate).value

            CustomerCollection.Add tCustomers, .customerID
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Module. "mExtendedCustomerDatabase". Here I'd like to add my whole collection to my ListBox.

```
Sub FillListBox(sListName As String)

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerDatabase")

    With frm_T1_Kundeoplysninger.Controls.Item(sListName)
        .AddItem CustomerCollection.Item("Kunde1") 'Type Mismatch-error
    End With

End Sub
```

To summarize. I'd like some guidelines on the easiest/fastest way to retrieve all items within my collection, and past them into my ListBox. Alternatives ways to do this, are accommodated aswell.

Comment: VBA doesn't work like some other langage platforms (eg. NET) where you can happily assign object to UI controls. `AddItem()` takes a string as the first parameter, not an object.  You will need to "manually" populate the listbox by explicitly coding the various column values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you fully - how am I suppose to add the collection's items then? Could you try explaining it differently, an coding example, or perhaps a link that explains it?

Comment: See chris' answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689812/identify-and-populate-a-listbox

Comment: Well .List(CustomerCollection) doesn't work either, nor does .addrange (CustomerCollection). I'm still stuck; how am I suppose to Fill the ListBox most comprehensive?

Comment: You need to follow the example code - you can't just assign your collection directly: you need to convert the strings you want to display into an array.

Comment: see [**THIS**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/two-column-listbox-userform-and-saving-results-to-spreadsheet/)

Comment: I've tried using this function (http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/iwebthereforeiam/2004/06/excel-vba-code-to-convert-coll.html), for converting my collection to an array, but is still getting an Type-match error. Something seems to be wrong whenever I try to retrieve anything from my collection. mehow: That link dosen't help me, course that's not my issue. I can easily add the items to my ListBox, but I'm not interested in using different functions than .additem - due to the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it. Converting my collection to an array, and setting my collection as inputparameter. Looping through my entire collection, and allocating it in an array. The issue seems to be related to .List-function, only allowing arrays as variant-datatype. It was solved; inspired by (http://www.iwebthereforeiam.com/iwebthereforeiam/2004/06/excel-vba-code-to-convert-coll.html).

```
Sub FillListBox(sListName As String)

    With frm_T1_Kundeoplysninger.Controls.Item(sListName)
        .List = ConvertCollectionToArray(CustomerCollection)
    End With

Clearing:
    Set CustomerCollection = Nothing

End Sub

Function ConvertCollectionToArray(cCustomers As Collection) As Variant()

    Dim arrCustomers() As Variant: ReDim arrCustomers(0 To cCustomers.Count - 1, 16)
    Dim i As Integer

    With cCustomers
        For i = 1 To .Count
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 0) = .Item(i).customerID
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 1) = .Item(i).customerName
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 2) = .Item(i).customerCompanyName
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 3) = .Item(i).customerFullName
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 4) = .Item(i).customerCVR
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 5) = .Item(i).customerType
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 6) = .Item(i).customerGroup
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 7) = .Item(i).customerCountry
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 8) = .Item(i).customerStreet
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 9) = .Item(i).customerZipcode
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 10) = .Item(i).customerCity
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 11) = .Item(i).customerPhoneNum
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 12) = .Item(i).customerMobileNum
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 13) = .Item(i).customerEmail
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 14) = .Item(i).customerInvoiceEmail
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 15) = .Item(i).customerCreationDate
            arrCustomers(i - 1, 16) = .Item(i).customerLastChange
        Next
    End With

    ConvertCollectionToArray = arrCustomers

End Function
```